# Get attributes for list of files

Tags: powershell, file, directory

I am not a coder, but know enough to do some simple tasks. Using Powershell

I need to get:

- folder/subfolder (s)/Filename.txt
- Mode
- LastWriteTime

Get-childItem and FullName work but file path too long..

I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force |foreach-object -process {$_.Fullname,LastWriteTime,Mode} >FullFileName.csv
```

and a number of other scripts I found online, Including this one

```
Get-ChildItem "MyFolderDirectory" | Select Name, @{ n = 'Folder'; e = { Convert-Path $_.PSParentPath } }, `
  @{ n = 'Foldername'; e = { ($_.PSPath -split '[\\]')[-2] } }
```

I just cant get what I want.. this is what I need, there has to be an easy way to do this, but I just am not skilled enough to figure it out.

```
-a---- 9/9/2019 9:39AM  folder1/folder2/Filename.txt
```

Comment: how do you want to shorten the `.FullFileName` property? do you just  want it relative to the directory listed in the `Get-ChildItem` call?

Comment: Do you mean you are getting an error "Path too long" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help you?

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | Foreach-Object { write-output "$($_.Mode) $($_.LastWriteTime) $($_.FullName)" }
```

This will grab the properties for each file or directory returned by `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: This is perfect!!! thank you so much, Im adding  ">filename.csv" to try to get it to write to a file. but it wont work, that is usually how I do it and it works fine.  not sure whats wrong

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Select-Object Mode, LastWriteTime, FullName
```

to get the list as array of objects. That way, it is also easy to export the results to a CSV file you can open in Excel for instance. To do that, simply append

```
 | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\filelist.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

to the above line. (change the `X:` to a existing drive on your machine of course)

Comment: Just did a cartwheel.. down my cubicle street!!! thank you so much for the help!!!